# How to pass callback while rendering column filter on react table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I am quite new to react and react-table, previously I had run the following code successfully on client-side filtering and now I am trying to update it to server-side filtering. My code looks as:

```
const ServerSideTable = ({ columns, data, tableMeta, fetchData }) => {
    const defaultColumn = React.useMemo(() => {
        return {
            Filter: ColumnFilter,
        };
    }, []);

    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        // rows,
        prepareRow,
        state,
        setGlobalFilter,
        page,
    } = useTable(
        {
            columns,
            data,
            defaultColumn,
            manualPagination: true,
            pageCount: tableMeta.totalPage,
        },
        useFilters,
        useGlobalFilter,
        useSortBy,
        usePagination
    );

    <table
        {...getTableProps()}
        id="basicTable"
    >
        <thead>
            {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                    {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                        <th
                            {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                            className="align-top"
                        >
                            <div
                                {...column.getSortByToggleProps()}
                            >
                                {column.render("Header")}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                {column.canFilter
                                    ? column.render(
                                          "Filter"
                                      )
                                    : ""}
                            </div>
                        </th>
                    ))}
                </tr>
            ))}
        </thead>

    </table>
}
```

and `ColumnFilter` looks as

```
const ColumnFilter = ({ column }) => {
    const { filterValue, setFilter } = column;
    const [value, setValue] = useState(filterValue);

    const onChange = useAsyncDebounce((value) => {
        setFilter(value || undefined);
    }, 1000);

    return (
        <input
            type="search"
            className="form-control form-control-sm d-inline-block"
            placeholder=""
            aria-controls="datatable"
            value={value || ""}
            onChange={(e) => {
                setValue(e.target.value);
                onChange(e.target.value);
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

What I want here, is the callback `handleSearchquuery` as `const ColumnFilter = ({ column, handleSearchQuery }) => {`

so that instead of calling `setFilter` on `onChange` I could call the callback.

At the moment, this filter is being rendered as:

```
{column.canFilter
    ? column.render(
          "Filter"
      )
    : ""}
```

Looks like this is the related docs, but couldn't get the idea.

https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useFilters#column-options

Comment: https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useFilters#column-options. Any help?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure react-table filtering can be done by the back-end as useTable has to be initialized with static data and filtering is done front-end on table formatted data. I usually do it externally by a component that can read the table instance and will feed useTable data property